# Android mini project

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to create a mini app project. I can't run my code because one of my methods is not working.

```
private void displayPrice(int number){
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);`
    priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
```

As you can see, the "(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number))"
has a red line under it, and it says Call requires API level 24(current min is 15) I have no idea how to update the api so this can work.

Comment: Need more info please, more code, maybe screen shot

Comment: re: `how to update the api level?` Open your POM and change this number in the configuration section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think should change your import to  `java.text.NumberFormat` instead of `android.icu.text.NumberFormat` but if you mean `android.icu.text.NumberFormat` then you should change `minSdkVersion` in your app gradle file to 24

Comment: Hey, thanks that worked. By the way now I cant run the app on my phone because the API on my phone is 21. AnyWay to update that? Thank You